# Displaying files matching a certain name format in UNIX

Tags: unix, expression, ls

Using an `ls` command, I'm trying to display all files that match a particular file name format. I've found ways to create various expressions to match, but I can't manage to create the right expression to match this specific format.

I'm looking to select files that:

- start with a letter (any case);
- contain a digit; and
- end with a period "." followed by a lowercase letter and one more character.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
ls | awk '/^[A-Za-z].*[0-9].*\.[a-z].$/{print $0}'
           ^                              Anchor to the beginning of the file name
            ^^^^^^^^                      Begins with letter
                    ^^                    0 or more any character
                      ^^^^^               A digit
                           ^^             0 or more any character
                             ^^           literal .
                               ^^^^^      A lower case letter
                                    ^     any single character
                                     ^    Anchor to the end of the file name
```